# Changing multiple XCode C++ Project Settings

Tags: c++, xcode, settings, project, workspace

I have an Apple XCode workspace with multiple C++ static library projects They all build under MacOS. I now want to build for iOS. However, I can't seem to be able to change the base SDK as a group. I need to do it project by project.

Is there a place to change them all in one step?

Thanks,

Stan